# IIS Network system hangs on multiple connections

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, networking, server

We have an asp.net core 5.0 web application hosted on IIS using Windows 10 as server. When about 30 people connect to the application, it will be working fine, and the system does not hang.

But the moment we put about 700 people on the application, the Windows 10 system will hang.
Please what settings can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is the well known restriction of Windows client OS. You have to use Windows Server OS.

Comment: Thanks Lex for your comment. I will give windows server a shot, and let you know if I have any hiccups. Thanks

Comment: Hi @LexLi, you were right, the issue is client OS, with windows server OS, the issue is solved. Thanks for the response